# Using Countifs Function in R for two dataframes

Tags: r

I am trying to replicate the COUNTIFS function in excel by comparing two data frames and getting the number of rows from a different data frame that meet the criteria.

So this is an example of what I am trying to do on a larger scale:

```
First DataFrame :
df <- data.frame(Amount = c (1000, 1500, 2000, 3000, 4000),
                 count = c(1, 1, 3, 2, 1))
df <- df[order(df$count, df$Amount),]
df

  Amount count
1   1000     1
2   1500     1
5   4000     1
4   3000     2
3   2000     3

Second DataFrame: 
Table1 <- data.frame(Amt = c(1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500, 5000),
                    Cnt = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1))
Table1

   Amt Cnt
1 1000   1
2 1500   2
3 2000   2
4 2500   1
5 3000   3
6 3500   1
7 4000   1
8 4500   3
9 5000   1
```

What I am trying to do is create a third column with the count the number of alerts from Table1 that meet both criteria from df using >=.

This is the desired outcome :

```
Amount  count   Countifs
1000    1   9
1500    1   8
4000    1   3
3000    2   2
2000    3   2
```

Its counting the number of rows in Table1 that are >= the Amount and count in df.

Formula in excel where column F & G are Table1 and column A & B are df

```
=COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$10,">="&$A2,$G$2:$G$10,">="&$B2)
```

These are previous codes I have tried

```
1. sum(rowSums(df$Amount >= Table1$Amt & df$count >= Table1$Cnt))
2. df$X <- length(which(df$Amount >= Amt & df$count >= Cnt))
3. library(dplyr)
   df %>%
   group_by(Amount, count) %>%
   count(Amount >= Table1$Amt,
        Count >= Table1$Cnt)
```

Comment: can you provide a desired outcome for your example? Not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think you want to simply count the total rows in df that are the same in Table1, and add these counts as a separate column to Table1. If yes, see my answer below.